# Exclude two times gaps from IF statment

Tags: c#, console-application, timespan

I'm trying to exclude two gaps in 24 hours from my `IF` statement.

I have 4 different hours:

1. `dstart = 06:00:00`
2. `dend = 19:00:00`
3. `start = 02:00:00`
4. `end = 03:00:00`

And `now` which is the current time.

I want to write a code and get it executed only if it doesn't fall under this category.

> IF NOW IS NOT IN BETWEEN
>    19:00:00 AND 02:00:00 AND
>    03:00:00 AND 06:00:00

Here's what I have.

```
if ((now > dend && now < start) || (now > end && now < dstart))
   {
      //skip
   }
else
   {
      //Do something
   }
```

If `now` is in any of these hours:

```
now = new TimeSpan(04,01,00);  // works
now = new TimeSpan(05,01,00);  // works
```

The `IF` statement works.

However, if the time is in between these hours

```
now = new TimeSpan(19,01,00);  
now = new TimeSpan(20,01,00);
now = new TimeSpan(21,01,00);
now = new TimeSpan(22,01,00);
now = new TimeSpan(23,01,00);
now = new TimeSpan(24,01,00);
now = new TimeSpan(01,01,00);
```

It fails and goes to `ELSE` statement. It shouldn't.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to compare `Datetime` not `Timespan`

Comment: @leppie at this time, it's too late for me to revert back to `Datetime` I'm doing other things with Timespan. Any suggestions on how I can resolve current issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the failing examples, Now is > dend, but not < start, and Now is > end, but not < dstart. Neither condition is passing, so it goes to the else.

--

```
if (now >= dend || now <= start  || (now >= end  && now < dstart))
   {
      //skip
   }
else
   {
      //Do something
   }
```

Comment: I figured that. But when I change `now > start` the other statement fails. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?